# Informations from frontend never reach the backend (jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, client-server, frontend

[image: The id is waht i expect]After login on admin page i try to use saveOrUpdate or delete but the id is not sended to the backend. Delete and saveOrUpdate are located in UserController and LogIn is in LoginCotroller, i think is a problem with sessions but i am pretty noob in client server apps. I used System.out.println to help me see what is happening in backend but from the start i recive null when i expect the id.
I used this jsp in another project without login and it was ok.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">

<% if (session.getAttribute("loggedInUserA").equals(1) ) { %>



     <input type="hidden" id="userId">
    Name:     <input type="text" id="name" required="required" name="name"><br>
    Password: <input type="text" id="password" required="required" name="password"><br>
    Acces:    <input type="text" id="acces" required="required" name="acces"><br>
    <button onclick="submit();">Submit</button>



    <table id="table" border=1>
        <tr> <th> Name </th> <th> Password </th> <th> Acces </th> <th> Edit </th> <th> Delete </th> </tr>

    </table>


<script type="text/javascript">
data = "";
submit = function(){

        $.ajax({
            url:'saveOrUpdate',
            type:'POST',
            data:{userId:$("#userId").val(),name:$('#name').val(),password:$('#password').val(),acces:$('#acces').val()},
            success: function(response){
                    alert(response.message);
                    load();    
            }              
        });        
}

delete_ = function(id){  
    console.log('id', id);

     $.ajax({
        url:'delete',
        type:'POST',
        data:{userId:id},
        success: function(response){
                alert(response.message);
                load();
        }              
    });



edit = function (index){
    $("#userId").val(data[index].userId);
    $("#name").val(data[index].name);
    $("#password").val(data[index].password);
    $("#acces").val(data[index].acces);

}


load = function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url:'list',
        type:'POST',
        success: function(response){
                data = response.data;
                $('.tr').remove();
                for(i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){   
                    console.log(response.data[i].userId);
                    $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> "+response.data[i].name+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].password+" </td> <td> "+response.data[i].acces+" </td>  <td> <a href='#' onclick= edit("+i+");> Edit </a>  </td> </td> <td> <a href='#' onclick='delete_("+response.data[i].userId+");'> Delete </a>  </td> </tr>");
                }          
        }              
    });

}

</script>


  <h2>
    <a href="/SpringMVC/">Back!!!</a>
</h2>

<% } else {
String redirectURL = "http://youtube.com";
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);  } %>
```

UserController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserServices userServices;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPage() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("admin");
        return view;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getSaved(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if (userServices.saveOrUpdate(user)) {
            map.put("status", "200");
            map.put("message", "Your record have been saved successfully");
        }

        return map;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getAll(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        List<User> list = userServices.list();

        if (list != null) {
            map.put("status", "200");
            map.put("message", "Data found");
            map.put("data", list);
        } else {
            map.put("status", "404");
            map.put("message", "Data not found");

        }

        return map;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> delete(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if (userServices.delete(user)) {
            System.out.println("UserController "+user.getUserId());
            map.put("status", "200");
            map.put("message", "Your record have been deleted successfully");
        }

        return map;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/page1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPage1() {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("user1");
        return view;
    }

}
```

LoginController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="user")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserServices userServices;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginForm() {
        return "login";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String verifyLogin(@RequestParam String name,@RequestParam String password, 
            HttpSession session,Model model) {

        User user=userServices.loginUser(name, password);
        if (user==null) {
            System.out.println("login control user null");
            model.addAttribute("loginError","Error logging in. Please try again");
            return "login";
        }
        session.setAttribute("loggedInUser", user);
        session.setAttribute("loggedInUserA", user.getAcces());
        return "admin";
    }
}
```

UserServiceImplementation

```
@Service
public class UserServicesImpl implements UserServices {

    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;
    @Override
    public List<User> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userDao.list();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("UserServices "+user.getUserId()+"  "+user.getName() +"  "+user.getPassword() + "  "+user.getAcces());
        return userDao.delete(user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("UserServices "+user.getUserId()+"  "+user.getName() +"  "+user.getPassword() + "  "+user.getAcces());
        return userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    public User loginUser(String name, String password) {
        User user=userDao.findUser(name);
        if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("User Login"+user.getUserId()+"  "+user.getName());
            return user;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

UserDaoImplementation

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {


    @Autowired
    SessionFactory session;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User").list();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            System.out.println("UserDaoImpl"+user.getUserId());
            session.getCurrentSession().delete(user);
        }catch(Exception ex) {
        return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        session.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public User findUser(String name) {
        Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        User user=(User) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name)).uniqueResult();
        return user;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the Ajax check if the id value is what you expect:

```
submit = function(){
   console.log($("#userId").val())
}
```

Comment: the id value is what i expect

Comment: You can check in the network tab of the browser how the request is sent. If the parameters are there it means they are not correctly mapped to the User class. Try to replace the User with simple fields.